# migration default child route from vue router v2 to vue router v3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

Migration guide says:

> Named children routes with an empty path no longer appends a slash
> his has an important side effect about children redirect records like these:

```
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/parent',
        component: Parent,
        children: [
          // this would now redirect to `/home` instead of `/parent/home`
          { path: '', redirect: 'home' },
          { path: 'home', component: Home },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

Notice:

> // this would now redirect to `/home` instead of `/parent/home`

But I would like to redirect to `/parent/home` instead of `/home`

Docs:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#named-children-routes-with-an-empty-path-no-longer-appends-a-slash

So how can one achieve original behaviour before this change with new router? I would like to have relative redirect to a child.

[Vue2 playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-router-nested-4fm5o5?file=/router.js) it works as expected.
[Vue3 playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-router-nested-broken-w0p08o?file=/src/router.js) broken by change.

Comment: I didn't tested it but does named routes works ? `redirect: { name: 'home' }`

Comment: yes, that's my current workaround, but I would like to use paths as more explicit solution and also then I don't need to name every route, also when different children route have same name, I would need to prefix them to have them uniq, like "product-summary" and "user-summary" instead of just summary. This complicates generalised components which routelinks to relative paths "summary". I would need to parametrise them to get correct summary routelink, which is terrible. I suppose there is adequate alternative of Vue2 solution in Vue3 which works same relative way as it was in Vue2 before. Thx